# Multi-valued function optimization with inequality constaints

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have the following function to maximize: $$f=\ln(1+(y-x))+\ln(1+(z-x))+\ln(1+(w-x))+\ln(1+(z-y))+\ln(1+(w-y))+\ln(1+(w-z))$$ subject to $x\ge 1, y\ge x, z \ge y, w \ge z, w \le 7$.

WolframAlpha says that local maxima is at $(x_0,y_0,z_0,w_0)=(1, 2.4, 5.6, 7)$.

But $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0,z_0,w_0) \approx 0.73 \ne 0$. Why is that?

Also, how do I solve it analytically? Lagrange multipliers? How to handle inequalities?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't use the gradient test with constrained optimization.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667568/definition-of-stationary-points-for-convex-optimization

Comment: The reason for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0,z_0,w_0)  \ne 0$ is that you have a constrained optimisation problem. Take a look at [karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush–Kuhn–Tucker_conditions)

Comment: why don't you compute all partial derivatives set them equal to Zero and solve this equation System?

Comment: Since you have a convex optimization problem (maximization of a convex function subject to linear constraints), a local maximum is a global maximum.